# Navigation viewport in mapbox

Tags: mapbox

may i please know if there's a feature in mapbox to create a navigation box which is a scaled version of main map.And can we create such  a navigation box such that any operation ex pan in navigation box will cause the main map to show the exact location corresponding to navigatoin box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing built into Mapbox for this but you can use the Leaflet MiniMap Plugin:
https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap to achieve this.